# Can anyone help me with the Windows API NetApi32?

Tags: .net, winapi, netapi32

I am trying to get a list of shares on a specific machine. So I decided to use the Windows API NetApi32.dll. Here is my code snippet:

```
Dim svr As String = Environment.MachineName
Dim level As Integer = 2
Dim sharesRead As Integer, totalEntries As Integer, nRet As Integer, hResume As Integer = 0
Dim pBuffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

nRet = NetApi32.NetShareEnum(svr, level, pBuffer, -1, sharesRead, totalEntries, hResume)
```

I'm getting a return code of 1231, but can't seem to find what that equates to. Can anyone point me in the correct direction on how to do this if it an incorrect way?

Comment: Have you tried investigating a way to solve your problem using .NET Framework constructs, rather than using Pinvoke?

Comment: Yeah , most solutions point to P/Invoke...I had a hard time looking for a pure .NET way. But from what my searches bring me, there isn't. Like I mentioned, if there is a better way of performing this, I would love to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681383(VS.85).aspx

ERROR_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE
1231 (0x4CF)

The network location cannot be reached.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your NetShareEnum definition valid? I am not very familar with VB.NET, but I have worked with netapi32 in c# in the past, and in general without problems.

But anyway, if you want to enumerate all shares on your computer, you can do it another way. 
In the following registry key you can find all current computer shares:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares

There is one key-value pair per share. Value is REG_MULTI_SZ type, that looks like simple ini. Check for "type=0" (file share), and read path.